# Add English nuances to Japanese "いいえ"

Tags: word-choice, translation, nuances

Here are some natural ways to say "no" in English (please forgive the language):

- No
- God no
- Hell no
- F*** no

How to include the English nuances in Japanese?

---

Best attempts:

- No - いいえ or ううん
- God no - 絶対いや
- Hell no - ありえへん or ありえない
- F*** no - ??

Motivating examples:

- Wanna eat soba again tonight? **No.**
- Do you want to travel on Golden Week? **God no.**
- Should we run another 10 miles? **Hell no.**
- Want to go to a Justin Bieber concert? **F*** no.**

Comment: "頭可笑しいか、お前⁈" - you'd likely just use very different expressions instead of modifying "No".

Comment: I must add that Japanese doesn't have as versatile a word as "f***". At least you have to ask yourself why: do you hate Justin Bieber? do you hate going concerts? do you hate he who invites you?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will start by saying that Japanese-speakers do not say 「いいえ」 nearly as often as English-speakers say "No".   「いいえ」 is simply not an everyday word for many of us the same way "No" is for English-speakers.

As an average Japanese-speaker, the first time I ever used 「いいえ」 more than a couple times a week in my life was when I started learning English in junior high school and was "***required***" to translate "No" to 「いいえ」 every time we saw the word "No" as a reply in the textbook.  It was painful as I was not accustomed to saying 「いいえ」 out loud.

**In Japanese, we answer questions negatively mainly by negating the main verb, adjective or noun used in the question itself**.

To the question "Wanna eat soba again tonight?", for instance, practically no Japanese-speakers will reply, 「いいえ」, believe it or not.  That would be an incredibly firm denial if someone actually replied that way.

Mild-to-medium negation:

「（ううん）、あまり/イマイチ/そんなに(Verb)たくない/(Na-adjective)じゃない/(I-adjective)くない。」

「（それは and/or ちょっと）ないかも。」、「（それは and/or ちょっと）ありえないかも。」、「（それは and/or ちょっと）ムリかな。」

「それはちょっと・・・」← Kinda versatile, but do not overuse it!

Strong negation:

「いや/いやだ、[絶対]{ぜったい}(Verb)たくない/(Na-adjective)じゃない/(I-adjective)くない。」

「そんなわけねぇだろっ！」、「そんなわけないだろっ！」、 「なわけないっしょ！」、「ありえねえよ！」(そんな＝んな＝な)

「(Verb)はず（or わけ）ねぇだろっ！」、「(Verb)たいわけねぇだろっ！」

「絶対（or 100パー）ムリ！」、「絶対ダメ！」、「絶対ない」, etc.

「100パー～～（たく）ない！」

I count on your ability to conjugate verbs and adjective to fit into these expressions.

Comment: +1. Also 無理 (by kids and young people)、ダメ、全然、etc. depending on context.